# Trying to blow up hi resolution photos 12" 38" 300dpi

Tags: large-format, scanner

I am trying to figure out the right scanner to buy. I make lampshades out of hi resolution photography and printthem out on a backlit film. I am trying to do a much larger lampshade then I have done before. The size is 12" wide by 38" long this will give me a 12"W by 12"L circle lampshade. The problem I am running into is the hi resolution images I have can not be blown up that big. So I wanted to photoshop a image about half of that say 6" wide by 17" long in 300dpi. I would like to put that image in the scanner and blow it up to 12" x 38" and have the image look crisp.  I need the print to be 300dpi b/c it is a lampshade and will be looked at up close.  I have done a lot of researchon different scanners with dpi up to 9600 these scanner says it can do hi res prints up to 20" x 30" but I think they are talking about from a film negative. If I start with a larger hi res photo and want to double its size or a bit more what scanner will work for me? Do I need something with 9600 dpi or can I get one with less b/c I am starting with a larger image that looks good in 300dpi. Any help is much appreciated this is my first time using a scanner to get an image this big for my lampshades.

Comment: You are barking up the wrong tree with the scanner. Option 1: Use software to upscale an image to the resolution you want. Option 2: Print the image, and scan it at the resolution you want. I think you'll get better results with Option 1. Scanners cannot magically create extra fine detail that doesn't exist in the original.

Comment: I will be putting the exact detail i want for the image in the scanner, just wanting to make it larger. All software upscaleing I have tried has not worked for the size I am going for. So will a scanner work if I am scanning a 300 dpi Image just wanting to make it larger. If there is any upscaleing software that anyone knows about I am open to all suggestions

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You think you've found a solution to your issue & are asking us how to achieve it. What you should be asking is how to achieve a solution your initial problem, not your assumed solution.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the [upscaling features in Photoshop](https://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/upscale-images-photoshop-cc-2018/)? You'll get a much higher quality image than you would doing the edit-print-scan-print method you're proposing.

Comment: I have a picture of a white wall that has no details/texture... what is it's resolution? It is 2400x3600px in size... what is it's resolution? Or instead it is 4800x7200px in size... what is it's resolution? I then print it at 300dpi and scan it at 9600dpi... what is it's resolution now?  And I want to print it onto white paper; ... what dpi resolution is required? Answer: In all cases it is zero. The point is that you need to start with the actual detail of the original image, which is almost certain to be less than it's pixel dimensions/PPI.

Comment: 300dpi is overkill. who looks at a lampshade close enough to discern between that and 150dpi?  Almost nobody over 30 will even be able to tell, even up close. Printer normally dither to a much higher dpi anyway to avoid "jaggies", and you can just do a resample to up-convert. There's a lot of popular resampling rituals that can yield slightly better results on some images if you want to go nuts.